# How do i get ng-if to reiterate the array?

Tags: angular

I have an element with an `*ng-for` on. It renders the data (an array of objects) perfectly. If i add an element, then i see the new data in my view.

```
<div *ng-for="#item of items" [attr.bob]="item.bob" />
```

If i modify an item in the list of items, i need that to be reflected in my view but it's not. How can i make this happen? I would be ok with triggering a full rendering of the whole array - and i can by adding/removing the element - but what would be best practice here? Perhaps there is a method to 'dirty' the #item ?

EDIT: I changed my code back to the original version that i couldn't get to work, because the version i just posted actually worked, nullifying this question. **I'm still curious if you can force a re-iteration manually** though so i'm leaving this question up. In case you are here looking for a solution, what i did was make something dependent on a property directly (index) instead of nested inside an object in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of the re-iterations actually. Attribute is binded to the element of the array and will change respectively. The change of the array also will be displayed automatically.

```
function RandomColorHex(){
  return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <button (click)="push()">add item</button>
    <p *ng-for="#item of items" [style.color]="item.color">{{ item.title }}</p>
  `,
  directives: [NgFor]
})
class AppComponent{
  constructor(){
    this.items = [
      {title:"foo", color:"red"},
      {title:"bar", color:"green"},
      {title:"baz", color:"blue"}
    ];

    setInterval(() => {
      let randomElement = this.items[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.items.length)];
      randomElement.color = RandomColorHex();
    }, 500);
  }
  push(){
    this.items.push({title:"i'm new here", color:"black"});
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kDBOclbBhWbXSt7Mgl11?p=preview)

Comment: I swear i tried excatly this (modifying a property on an element in the array) and failed. I don't know why it didnt work then, but works now.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set the value of [attr.something] somewhere which would then force a refresh?

Comment: This was actually what the code you commented on did and it turned out - my code was already working. I'm upvoting your answer since now it's actually an answer to my new post ;)